# How to fix Fn keys in 17.04

Tags: lubuntu, thinkpad, media-buttons

Just moved to Lubuntu and my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys for volume control, screen brightness, etc. don't function properly. I'm coming from Elementary OS where that worked stock, so I'm hoping to get a little help making the standard functionality of this keyboard fully realised.

If it is important, the keyboard in question is that of a Thinkpad x240.

Comment: I hope someone here can help you, but if you don't get the answers you need, another good place to ask that's 
chock-full of Thinkpad and Linux geeks is http://reddit.com/r/thinkpad

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `xinput`? You can also run `xev | tee xev.log`, focus the newly opened window and press the media key(s) to test if they produce any events at all. If you're unsure you can include the relevant section of the file `xev.log` that is produced by the same command. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? I have a similar problem that my FN Keys on my X1 yoga stopped working (they already worked after the upgrde to 17.04). Would be nice if you share your knowledge with us.